# Chaining Enumerations for hierarchical naming structures?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

Since I have a terrible memory, I like to put all the detnd I ails of data objects into enumerations, so I can use code completion in the IDE adon't have to keep referring back to get the name of a table or the name of a field.  Usually I use some type of class containing only Enums for the purpose.

Lets say I have table of "Domains" (database source) "Tables" and "Fields" that look something like this:

```
public class DataObjectNames {
    public enum Domains {
        Domain1,
        Domain2;
    }

    public enum Domain1Tables {
        Customers,
        Orders;
    }

    public enum Domain2Tables {
        OrderItems,
        Shipments;
    }

    public enum CustomerFields {
        id,
        email;
    }

    public enum OrderFields {
        id,
        customerId;
    }
    //fields for OrderItems and Shipments . . .
}
```

But suppose I wanted to be able to do something like:

```
Domain1.tables().Customers.fields().  //code completion supplies choices?
```

What I would like ot happen after I type the period is for autocomplete to provide a choice between .id and     .email, much the same as it would if "fields" returned an object with two methods, or if I just typed 
    CustomerFields.
in the IDE.

In order for that to happen, it seems to me I somehow need to return not a specific instance of an enumeration, but the enumeration itself.  I've tried various approaches like this:

```
public enum Domains {
        Domain1 {
            @Override
            public Enum<?> tables() {
                return Domain1Tables.foo();
            } //Is there a method that will return the enum itself?
        },
        Domain2 {
            @Override
            public Enum<?> tables() {
            return Domain2Tables.foo();
        };

        public abstract Enum<?> tables();
    }
```

But of course I haven't been able to find a funciton foo() that returns the enum class itself.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with enums because Java's class model doesn't work the way you would need in order for this style to work.

*I haven't been able to find a function foo() that returns the enum class itself.*

Returning the enum class itself is easy, you just do `Domain1Tables.class`, but that won't give you the completion you want because what it gives you is a `Class<Domain1Tables>` object, and that object doesn't have fields named `Customers` and `Orders`.

You want to be able to treat the "Domain1Tables" class as if it's an object and refer to the enum constants (which are effectively static final fields) as if they were members of that object, but Java simply doesn't do that.

If you give up on using `enum`s for it, then you can simply have:

```
public class DataObjectNames {

    public class Domains {

        class Domain1 {
            class Tables {
                class Customers {
                    public static final String id = "id";
                    public static final String email = "email";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in that case `DataObjectNames.Domains.Domain1` wouldn't be a valid expression anymore (because it reference to a class scope, but not to an object.

There's probably a solution to what you're trying to do, but without more context I can provide anything more details than what's above.

Comment: Thanks.  I've come to the same conclusion.  It actually turns out to be easier to reverse the heirarchy, and create the enums as standalones, but with accessor methods to access their parent, as in CustomerFields.table which returns a member of the Tables enum, or alternatively the TableEnum can have a method which returns an EnumSet of the tables field enum (e.g. Customers.fields() returns EnumSet.allOf(CustomerFields), which is handy for iteration.